# appendTo not working for this function yet append works

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

Ok, So I have over 1000 lines of jQuery code, and other functions are also using appendTo and it works.

However it seems that the following function appendTo wont work, while append does work.

I think it is because I am creating the DIV in the jquery file and the asking another function to fill that div. but am not sure if that is the reason.

here is the function that is playing up.

```
function getmessage(e) {
    $('#loadmessage').html("");
    $.getJSON('sys/classes/usermessage.php?task=fetch&subkey=' + e + '&userid=' + sessionparts[1], function(getmessage) {
        // get line status
        $.each(getmessage, function(i, item) {

            $('#loadmessage').append(item.subkey);
        });
    });    
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code that does not work - using appendTo

Comment: the appove code. however it does not matter, as I found that it works the way I need it to at the end of the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `.appendTo()` will not work in this case because your `item.subkey` is not a dom element. You have 2 choices.

1) Use `.append()` as your code is now

2) For using `.appendTo()` put your item.subkey in a dom node, as the following:

```
$.each(getmessage, function(i, item) {
    $("<span />").text(item.subkey).appendTo('#loadmessage');
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers